# Creating Custom library in Zend Framework 1.10

Tags: zend-framework, libraries

I want to create my custom libraries in zendframework 1.10 and use them in controller. 
e.g suppose i want to create library for conversion rate of products and use them in my pricecontrooler

How can we do this ?? Any Guess

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `autoloader` of zend:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html

Quick example usage: just add `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "<mylibrary_namespace>"` to your `application.ini` where `<mylibrary_namespace>` is the namespace of your library. Make sure you put the whole `<mylibrary>` library inside `\library\<mylibrary>` folder.

*So assuming the namespace is `MyLibrary`:*

application.ini:

```
[...]

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

[...]

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "MyLibrary"
```

in your controller:

```
[...]

$MyLibrary = new MyLibrary();

[...]
```